# How to remove last 4 character before saving data to txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that saves image names from folder to txt file, but before i'm saving them i want to remove .png

How can i do it?

```
@echo
SET path = "C:\Documents\Img"
dir /b %path % > myImg.txt
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension

Comment: Note: when using `set` it is not a good idea to have spaces around the `=` as it adds a space to the variable name ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution (with great help from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension) that just gets the filename (minus extension) and outputs the list to a file:

(I've edited my answer to match your directory/file)

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Documents\Img" %%f in (*.*) do (
    echo %%~nf >>myImg.txt
)
pause
```

The script will continually append to the `pics.txt` file so if you need it to write a fresh file each time then you'll need to add an initial step to overwrite the file with an empty string (`break>myImg.txt`):

```
@echo off
break>myImg.txt
for /R "C:\Documents\Img" %%f in (*.*) do (
    echo %%~nf >>myImg.txt
)
pause
```

Comment: Would've been even better if you had edited it to use his path rather than the one from the other question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search [for remove file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215539).

You can use a `for` loop iterating throug `%path` and echo/write `%%~nf` to your file.